# undefined reference to <function name>

Tags: c, gcc, header-files

I have this simple test file:

```
#include "stack.h"

int main()
{
  Stack* stck = init_stack();

  return 0;
}
```

and `stack.h` is defined as follows:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#define EMPTY_STACK -1
typedef struct stack
{
  char ch;
  struct stack* prev;
} Stack;

extern Stack* init_stack();

extern char pop(Stack*);

extern void push(Stack*, char);

#endif
```

These two files are in the same directory. But when I do `gcc ..` to build it, I keep getting the error below:

```
$ ls
stack.c  stack.h  teststack.c
$ gcc -o testit teststack.c 
/tmp/ccdUD3B7.o: In function `main':
teststack.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `init_stack'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could anyone tell me what I did wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: How does it know where the definition of `init_stack` that is has to use is? Though it includes C++, this question will probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Note that `extern Stack *init_stack();` is a quite different declaration from `extern Stack *init_stack(void);`.  The first says there is a function but the argument list is not specified (it's not a variable arguments function, but the number and types of the arguments are not specified).  The second says the function takes no arguments.  Don't use the empty parentheses notation in C.  Note that in C++, empty parentheses mean the same as `(void)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, wow! I never knew that! I always thought `(void)` is just the fancy way of `()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
 gcc -o testit teststack.c stack.c
```

You need to compile both C source files and link the object files; this does it all in one command.

Comment: I thought the `#include "stack.h"` should take care of it? No?

Comment: @user1508893, All including that does is basically paste it in the including file. `stack.c` can't magically work its way in.

Comment: (a) The `#include "stack.h"` copies the information from `stack.h` into the `teststack.c` file, giving the compiler information about the function — but not giving its definition.  (b) No, you don't need to add `stack.h` to the command line.  Both the source files will include `stack.h` as the source is preprocessed before the compilation really gets going.

Comment: @chris: If all `#include` does is to paste the content of the included file into the including file, then it'd be even more unnecessary to include the `stack.c` in the `gcc` because we no longer need it? (the content is already in `teststack.c` ?

Comment: The implementation of the function `init_stack()` is not in the header `stack.h` (and it should not be there).  Presumably, the implementation is in `stack.c`; that needs to be compiled so that the linker gets to see the definition of `init_stack()`.

Comment: I think it should be clear by now, but C does not have a module system or anything that comes close. `#include`s are a primitive way to accomplish this, but have these gotchas.